# How to have delay after every Timer.periodic

Tags: flutter, timer

I am using the `Timer.periodic` code below for every X seconds to send a message to another device using my costumize `_sendmessage` function to make sure that there is still connection.

```
@override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) => 
        _sendmessage('Alive'));
    }
    
    @override
    void dispose() {
      timer?.cancel();
      super.dispose();
    }
```

My problem is I also use `_sendmessage` on sending other data to another device such as when a button is pressed. Therefore there is a chance that the button is pressed and `Timer.periodic` can happen at the same time or right after one another causing loosing data received by another device. (This another device can only read 1 string at a time).

How to have delay after every `Timer.periodic` to make sure the above case will not happen?

Comment: You should update your _sendmessage method to block until it’s safe to send a message rather than rely on timers to attempt to avoid race conditions.

Comment: Is `_sendmessage` asynchronous?  Can the caller determine when it is complete and the receiver is ready for another message?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a variable called "isSendingData". Whenever you call `_sendmessage`, update it to `true` and after finish, update it to `false`.

If your button is pressed, you can check if `isSendingData == true` and don't trigger action `_sendmessage` again.

But I think the problem is in your another device - there may be something wrong when it receives data. Hope you will find someways to make it possible to receives second data right after the first one.